# App Script date date is of by one day if reading from from google spreadsheet

Tags: date, google-apps-script, calendar, spreadsheet

I like to read a date from a Google spreadsheet to check my Google calendar for entries. But the date `getEventsForDay( )` function retuns the entries fo the previous date as expected.
Example: I like to get the entries to 24.12.2020 but my code returns the entries to 23.12.2020

This is my spreadsheet
[cell 2,2 contains the date 24.12.2020](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nhKbZ.png)

This is my calendar:
[calender holding entries on 23.,24. and 25.12.2020](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jMtcK.png)

My Code:

```
function exampleDateIsOff() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var range_date = sheet.getRange(2,2);
  var date = new Date(range_date.getValue());
  Logger.log("Date from cell: " + Utilities.formatDate(date, SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSpreadsheetTimeZone(),'MMMM dd, yyyy'));
  Logger.log("ScriptTimeZone: " + Session.getScriptTimeZone());
  Logger.log("SheetTimeZone:  " + SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSpreadsheetTimeZone());
  Logger.log("CalendarApp:  " + CalendarApp.getTimeZone());
  var calendar = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(calendarId);
  var events = calendar.getEventsForDay(date);
  for (i = 0; i < events.length; i++) {
        Logger.log(events[i].getTitle());
  }
}
```

The output:

```
Info    Date from cell: December 24, 2020
Info    ScriptTimeZone: America/New_York
Info    SheetTimeZone:  Europe/Vienna
Info    CalendarApp:  Europe/Vienna
Info    Dez 23
```

Comment: What is the value of `date.getTime()` ?

Answer (score 0):

I referenced this post here:
https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/73235/how-do-i-get-a-date-formatted-as-yyy-mm-dd-from-a-cell-for-using-in-a-script

Remove the `updateConfig();` from the second line, it is undefined.
Change these two lines:

```
    var date = new Date(range_date.getValue());
    Logger.log("Date from cell: " + Utilities.formatDate(date, 
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSpreadsheetTimeZone(),'MMMM dd, yyyy'));
```

To this:

```
    var date = range_date.getValue();
    var formattedStartDate = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(date), 
    ss.getSpreadsheetTimeZone(), "MMMM dd, yyyy"); 
    Logger.log("Date from cell: " + formattedStartDate);
```

The third log you have here:

```
    Logger.log("SheetTimeZone:  " + 
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSpreadsheetTimeZone());
```

can be shortened to this:

```
    Logger.log("SheetTimeZone:  " + ss.getSpreadsheetTimeZone());
```

as you already have a variable 'ss' for calling the App and Active Spreadsheet.

Leave your `var events = calendar.getEventsForDay(date);` as-is, it needs to be a string value.

I think the issue was trying to change the string value in your cell that you are using in the script to a javascript date item too soon, you need to be able to call the string value that you have there. Someone who knows about the Utilities.formateDate more would be able to answer that better, but I think this will change it so you can call whatever date you have in your cell. I don't know what time zone you are aiming for though, your logs have both Europe/Vienna and America/New York.

Example logs for putting in "4/4/21" in the B2 cell:

```
    4:31:59 AM  Notice  Execution started
    4:31:59 AM  Info    Date from cell: April 04, 2021
    4:31:59 AM  Info    ScriptTimeZone: America/Indiana/Indianapolis
    4:31:59 AM  Info    SheetTimeZone:  America/Indianapolis
    4:31:59 AM  Info    CalendarApp:  America/New_York
    4:31:59 AM  Info    Easter Sunday
    4:32:00 AM  Notice  Execution completed
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue now by using `getEvents`

```
<----
  var events = calendar.getEventsForDay(date);
----> 
  var end_date = new Date(date);
  end_date.setDate(end_date.getDate() + 1)
  var events = calendar.getEvents(date, end_date)
```

```
function exampleDateIsOff() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var range_date = sheet.getRange(2,2);
  var date = new Date(range_date.getValue());
  Logger.log("Date from cell: " + Utilities.formatDate(date, ss.getSpreadsheetTimeZone(),'MMMM dd, yyyy'));
  Logger.log("ScriptTimeZone: " + Session.getScriptTimeZone());
  Logger.log("SheetTimeZone:  " + ss.getSpreadsheetTimeZone());
  Logger.log("CalendarApp:  " + CalendarApp.getTimeZone());
  var calendar = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(calendarId);
  var end_date = new Date(date);
  end_date.setDate(end_date.getDate() + 1)
  var events = calendar.getEvents(date, end_date)
  for (i = 0; i < events.length; i++) {
        Logger.log(events[i].getTitle());
  }
}
```